# Unable to configure font in XTerm

Tags: xterm, fontconfig

After a lot of mucking around Xterm, poring through reams of webpages I have thrown in the towel and realized that this isn't something I can figure out on my own.

**TrueType vs Bitmap**

1. Is the option `xterm*font` used to specify only bitmap fonts and is `*faceName` used only for TrueType fonts?
2. I'm using the commands `xlsfonts` and `fc-list` to find out the Bitmap and TrueType fonts that are installed. Is this correct?
3. I want to set the XTerm font to Ubuntu Mono. This is the output of `fc-list | grep -i ubuntu`

   ```
   Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline
   Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=Bold Italic
   Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=BoldForPowerline
   Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=ItalicForPowerline
   ```

and I added `XTerm*faceName: Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline`
 to my `~/.Xresources` and ran `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

`xrdb -query all` shows that `*faceName` is set to `Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline`

However, this doesn't work. What am I missing/screwing up here?

EDIT: I finally figured out what's wrong just a couple of days ago after scrounging through multiple sources. Combining everyone's responses here:

Ubuntu Mono is a TrueType font and TrueType fonts require xterm to be compiled with FreeType library support. To check whether xterm has this, use the `ldd /path/to/xterm/binary` command and see if it says freetype in there. An alternate way is to see if xterm has the `-fa` option.

If your xterm has FreeType lib support, choose a

1. Bitmap fonts, by running `xfontsel -p` and use the exact string it prints upon exit.
2. TrueType fonts, using `fc-list :scalable=true:spacing=mono: family` and use the exact string it outputs.

Once you have the font name using one of the above steps, set it via `XTerm*faceName: <name of the font>`

If you install a new font, and it doesn't show up when you run one of the above commands, rebuild your font cache using `fc-cache -frv` and try again.

Hope this helps; please let me know in case I've missed anything.

P.S. I used Ubuntu Mono patched font downloaded from [here](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) I'm using `XTerm*faceName: "Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Point by point:

1. yes, the `font` resource is a standard resource setting for the X Toolkit, which deals only with [XLFD](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/XLFD/xlfd.html) (bitmap), while `faceName` was added long after, in applications such as [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) to provide a way to specify TrueType fonts (actually whatever fontconfig supports, which can include bitmap fonts).
2. the [`xlsfonts`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xlsfonts) and [`fc-list`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fc-list) programs are used for the two (XLFD and [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/)) respectively.
3. The style looks ... odd.  I added the `.ttf` files from [github](https://github.com/pdf/ubuntu-mono-powerline-ttf) to my `~/.fonts` directory (the [zip-file link](https://github.com/pdf/ubuntu-mono-powerline-ttf/archive/master.zip) is the simplest way to download).
4. I unzipped the download unzip my `~/.fonts` directory rather than copying the `.ttf` files into the top-level directory.  fontconfig can deal with subdirectories; it may be sensitive to the actual filenames.  For instance, if I had copied the files to the top-level `~/.fonts` directory, `fc-list` would show the full pathname of the font-files (probably not correct).
5. `fc-list` shows me `Regular` where you have `RegularForPowerline`.

Here is the output of `fc-list`, looking for "Power":

```
Ubuntu Mono for VimPowerline:style=Bold
Ubuntu Mono for VimPowerline:style=Bold Italic
Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=Bold Italic
Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=Regular
Ubuntu Mono for VimPowerline:style=Italic
Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=Bold
Ubuntu Mono for VimPowerline:style=Regular
Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=Italic
```

By the way, you could test the fonts directly using the command-line `-fa` option (quoting the face-name, of course).  I did that, and the result looks plausible (comparing regular and bold).

Comment: I deleted my old fonts and downloaded [these](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/UbuntuMono) as they were linked from the Powerline repo. However, now when I run `fc-list`, I don't see Ubuntu Mono in there. I tried refreshing the font cache via `fc-cache -fv`; however it says _error scanning_

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see the `-fa` option and that was because my XTerm didn't have FreeType library support. Compiling XTerm with it allows me to use TrueType fonts now.